# How do you read the file-path of a file that has been set to open your application by default?

Tags: c#, winforms

I wish to be able to open my C# forms application (image viewer) with, for example, a jpg or gif. What would I have to do to allow the application to read the file-path of that file so that it can process it accordingly?

The application is working fine; all I need to do now is make sure that it can display a picture immediately if it is set to the default for images like jpg, gif etc.

Comment: The application simply displays an image that the user picks from their computer. It uses Image.FromFile(path).

Comment: I think he wants to associate his application with a file type - making the application appear under _Open In..._ when right-clicking a JPG or GIF, and making it properly receive the file.

Comment: Check your command line arguments. It will contain the full path to the file to be opened if you have already set your app as the default program to open such files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs ();](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

As the documentation describe:

> The first element in the array contains the file name of the executing
>   program. If the file name is not available, the first element is equal
>   to String.Empty. The remaining elements contain any additional tokens
>   entered on the command line.

So, in your case, the image file path that 'starts'your application should be the second element of the array returned by Environment.GetCommandLineArgs ().

Comment: This appears to be the answer I was looking for. The path of the file that was used to open the application seems to be the second value (array[1]) when you send that to a string array. I will give you an up-vote but I will see if anyone gives a more comprehensive answer before I accept it.